# Android - SimpleCursorAdapter ListView can not click

Tags: android, listview, click, simpleadapter

I want to use listview with SimpleCursorAdapter Class. My problem is I can not click list view.
My Adapter class is....

```
public class ColorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private Context context;

    public ColorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return MyArrList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list, null);
        }

        TextView tname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ename);
        tname.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("EventName"));

        TextView tdetail = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.edetail);// ใส่ข้อมูลทีละส่วน
        tdetail.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("EventDetail"));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

On click method is....

```
elist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EventsDetail.class);
            String eventName = MyArrList.get(position).get("EventName").toString();

            intent.putExtra("EventName", eventName);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

When I click listview it nothing happen. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this issue a few days ago, the problem shoube be exist in the list-row-layout, in your list-row layout xml root element, put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`, it works for me well.

hope it helpful!